# Не создал ли я то, что и до меня было создано? Есть ли альтернатива?

Tags: c++

Создал класс который называется TypePairs. В чем идея. 
Создавая объект класса TypePair мы указываем пары ключ-значение. Далее по ключу мы можем получить значение (или по индексу пары). В качестве ключа и значения здесь типы данных.

```
auto tp = makeTypePairs(std::string(), std::regex(), int(), bool(true), std::wstring(), std::wregex(L"Hello World!"));

tp.getPair<int>()->getValue();            // return bool(true)
tp.getPair<std::wstring>()->getValue();   // return std::wregex(L"Hello World!")
tp.getPair<std::string>()->getValue();    // return std::regex()

tp.getPairByIndex<1>()->getValue();       // return bool(true)
```

Это может пригодится например в такой ситуации

```
// Вариант 1
template<class T>
void foo1(std::basic_string<T> str)
{
    std::basic_regex<T> r(str);
    ...
}

// Вариант 2
template<class T>
void foo2(T str)
{
    auto ur = ONF::makeTypePairs(std::string(), std::regex(), std::wstring(), std::wregex());
    auto r = ur.getPairValueType<T>(str);
    ...
}

int main()
{
    // Вариант 1
    foo1<char>("Hello");
    foo1<wchar_t>(L"Hello");

    // Вариант 2
    foo1<std::string>("Hello");
    foo1<std::wstring>(L"Hello");
}
```

Да, первый вариант выглядит более деликатно, но он не всегда подходит. 
Вопрос. Есть ли где-нибудь более профессиональная реализация такой штуки.

Comment: Делал [похожее решение](https://github.com/BG4444/opt-parser), только у меня строковые ключи, а строки конвертируются в индексы во время компиляции.

Comment: @gbg , а есть ли такое в какой-нибудь популярной библиотеке вроде Boost (или даже std)

Comment: Ну, вы изобрели [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), на самом деле, только у него доступ по индексам, а не по типам

Comment: @gbg , ну тут весь смысл в доступе по типу, а доступ по индеку это так, приятный бонус.

Comment: У стандартного тепла есть такая возможность через [std:: get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get)

Comment: @KoVadim , возможно я что-то упускаю, но это, вроде, не то что я имел ввиду. Суть моего класса в том, что создаваемый объект состоит из пар ключ-значение. Мы по типу ключа получаем тип значения. Файлы класса: [header](https://github.com/lelezard7/ONF/blob/dev/include/UniversalDefinitions.h), [inl](https://github.com/lelezard7/ONF/blob/dev/include/TypePairs.inl). В std::tuple мы можем найти тот или иной тип и получить его значение, но tuple не имеет формат ключ-значение (насколько известно мне).

Comment: Возможно, будет более конструктивно, если вы напишете, какую задачу решает ваш контейнер. Не *что он делает* (это вы уже написали), а *для чего это нужно*.

Comment: @ArtemiiSelyankin как по мне, то тупл вполне себе "мапа", ключами являются типы, а значения - они собственно и хранятся в тупле. `std::tuple<const char*, const wchar_t*> lang = {"test", L"test"};   std::cout << std::get<const char*>(lang);` - очень похоже на Ваш пример.

Comment: Надо решить, что именно является ключом, а что значением. Вы храните ключи как объекты, но в обоих примерах ищите по типу - значит ключи хранятся зря. В первом примере значением является объект, а во втором тип - значит во втором сами значения тоже хранятся зря.